# Trouble in handling ajax array list

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have strange problem in handling array list of ajax result.

I am passing an `ID` in function and fetching results on the basis of that Id-

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
GetDates('@Model[i].contact_id');
}
```

**Function-**

```
 var arrAcquiredDates = [];
    function GetDates(contactid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Service/ServicesRenewalDates/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { Id: contactid },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        for (var i = 0; i < JSON.stringify(data.countof.Length) ; i++);
                        {
                            arrAcquiredDates.push('<tr><td colspan="4">' + data.list[i].DateAcquired + ' To ' + data.list[i].DateRenewal + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                        $('#tl-' + contactid).after(arrAcquiredDates);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Hereby this function invokes method from the controller and fetches back result with array list in it-

```
 public JsonResult ServicesRenewalDates(long? Id)
        {
            Bal b = new Bal();
            List<ServiceModel> services = new List<ServiceModel>();
            services = b.ServicesRenewalDates(Id);
            return Json(new { list = services, countof = services.Count }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**See in table-**

[image]

Here is the part of UI table. If you note the returned number is `2` for first row, So ajax delivers loop for 2 times and fetches me related results that I am appending in the list.
But from image you can see it here that it does just reverse of wanted result. Where `Returned` number is 2; it returns one row and for `1` it returns two rows.

I am experiencing something went wrong in ajax handling.

My console result is something like this-

[image]

And now at last the part where I am rendering list in table-

```
 <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Returned Times</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr id="tl-@item.contact_id">
                            <td>@item.customerName
                            </td>
                            <td>@item.countCustomers</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How do I handle this ajax result in right way?

Comment: There seems no point in returning `countof`. All you need is `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Also `data.countof.Length` will return `1` if the value is between 1 and 9 so that makes no sense (if the collection returned 8 items its still only going to loop once). And you keep appending new rows to `arrAcquiredDates`, which is why you are seeing these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not necessary to return the count of the list and you action method can be simplified to

```
public JsonResult ServicesRenewalDates(long? Id)
{
  Bal b = new Bal();
  List<ServiceModel> services = b.ServicesRenewalDates(Id);
  return Json(services, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in the ajax success callback loop through item in the collection to build a table row and append it to the DOM

```
success: function (data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').append($('<td colspan="4"></td>').text(item.DateAcquired + ' to ' + item.DateRenewal));
    $('#tl-' + contactid).after(row);
  });
```

Note also, if `services` contains properties other than just `DateAcquired` and `DateRenewal` you should create a collection of anonymous objects to minimize the data transferred back to the client

```
services = b.ServicesRenewalDates(Id)
  .Select(s => new
  {
    DateAcquired = s.DateAcquired,
    DateRenewal = s.DateRenewal
  });
```